# Why does the choice of solver result in different weight in sklearn (LogisticRegression)

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Why do different solvers result in different learned weights on simple problems in sklearn?
This doesn't smell like numerical instability -- it looks like the different solvers are designed to converge on different sets of weights.
What's going on?

It seems to be related to regularization, as the effect goes away with increasing C

```
%matplotlib inline
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model.logistic import LogisticRegression

def linear(X,b): return X.dot(b.T)
def sigmoid(X,b): return 1/(1+np.exp(-linear(X,b)))

b = np.array([1.,1.])

def mk(X,y,model):
    model.fit(X,y)
    t = time.clock()
    c = np.concatenate((model.coef_[0,:], model.intercept_[[0]]))
    return c, time.clock()-t

max_iter = 1000
tol=0.00000001
for C in [0.0001, 0.001, 0.1, 1., 10., 1000.]:
    for n in [200, 20000]:
        x = np.arange(-5., 5, 10./n)
        Xb = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
        p = sigmoid(Xb,b)
        y = np.random.binomial(1, p)
        X = x.reshape((len(x), 1))
        print C, n
        for solver in ["liblinear", "newton-cg", "lbfgs", "sag"]:
            print "  {:>14}".format(solver), mk(X,y, LogisticRegression(C=C, solver=solver, penalty='l2', max_iter=max_iter, tol=tol))
```

The converged coefficients are below. The training data is generated with B=[1., 1.]

```
C      n
0.0001 200
       liblinear (array([ 0.01858615,  0.00219137]), 1.399999999995849e-05)
       newton-cg (array([ 0.01867489,  0.44809872]), 1.5000000000098268e-05)
           lbfgs (array([ 0.01867489,  0.44809872]), 1.5000000000098268e-05)
             sag (array([ 0.01867489,  0.448096  ]), 1.3000000000040757e-05)
0.0001 20000
       liblinear (array([ 0.49062599,  0.14814571]), 2.6999999999999247e-05)
       newton-cg (array([ 0.51257455,  0.59982733]), 2.6000000000081513e-05)
           lbfgs (array([ 0.51257471,  0.59982645]), 2.8999999999834714e-05)
             sag (array([ 0.51257455,  0.59982753]), 1.3000000000040757e-05)
0.001 200
       liblinear (array([ 0.15311436,  0.0154459 ]), 1.2999999999596668e-05)
       newton-cg (array([ 0.15456163,  0.34240309]), 1.3000000000040757e-05)
           lbfgs (array([ 0.15456166,  0.34240284]), 1.3000000000040757e-05)
             sag (array([ 0.15456163,  0.34240308]), 1.100000000020529e-05)
0.001 20000
       liblinear (array([ 0.81980482,  0.58214727]), 3.799999999998249e-05)
       newton-cg (array([ 0.86826695,  0.87335432]), 3.0999999999892225e-05)
           lbfgs (array([ 0.86826513,  0.87335497]), 3.2000000000032e-05)
             sag (array([ 0.86826695,  0.87335433]), 2.9999999999752447e-05)
0.1 200
       liblinear (array([ 0.80161404,  0.39606419]), 2.3999999999801958e-05)
       newton-cg (array([ 0.82243805,  0.57384594]), 2.9000000000056758e-05)
           lbfgs (array([ 0.82243822,  0.57384605]), 3.0000000000196536e-05)
             sag (array([ 0.82243805,  0.57384595]), 2.4999999999941735e-05)
0.1 20000
       liblinear (array([ 0.98022283,  0.97426356]), 3.799999999998249e-05)
       newton-cg (array([ 0.98180586,  0.98060186]), 2.3999999999801958e-05)
           lbfgs (array([ 0.98181404,  0.98060174]), 3.1000000000336314e-05)
             sag (array([ 0.98180586,  0.98060185]), 3.0999999999892225e-05)
1.0 200
       liblinear (array([ 0.77546388,  0.68083769]), 2.3999999999801958e-05)
       newton-cg (array([ 0.78084612,  0.71273566]), 1.1999999999900979e-05)
           lbfgs (array([ 0.7808462 ,  0.71273586]), 1.3000000000040757e-05)
             sag (array([ 0.78084612,  0.71273566]), 1.0000000000065512e-05)
1.0 20000
       liblinear (array([ 1.01286416,  1.01699803]), 3.1000000000336314e-05)
       newton-cg (array([ 1.013046  ,  1.01769302]), 1.6000000000016e-05)
           lbfgs (array([ 1.0130471 ,  1.01769538]), 3.0999999999892225e-05)
             sag (array([ 1.013046  ,  1.01769301]), 2.0999999999826713e-05)
10.0 200
       liblinear (array([ 1.19187232,  1.52139602]), 9.999999999621423e-06)
       newton-cg (array([ 1.19737431,  1.53737059]), 4.300000000023729e-05)
           lbfgs (array([ 1.19737519,  1.53736531]), 1.8999999999991246e-05)
             sag (array([ 1.19737429,  1.53737061]), 1.700000000059987e-05)
10.0 20000
       liblinear (array([ 0.9993963,  0.9748259]), 9.19999999995369e-05)
       newton-cg (array([ 0.9994126 ,  0.97489034]), 3.0999999999892225e-05)
           lbfgs (array([ 0.99941332,  0.97489202]), 3.10000000007804e-05)
             sag (array([ 0.99941261,  0.97489035]), 1.4000000000180535e-05)
1000.0 200
       liblinear (array([ 1.31759982,  1.48775989]), 9.000000000369823e-06)
       newton-cg (array([ 1.3176617 ,  1.48792683]), 1.4000000000180535e-05)
           lbfgs (array([ 1.31766183,  1.48792601]), 4.499999999918458e-05)
             sag (array([ 1.31766164,  1.48792671]), 1.100000000064938e-05)
1000.0 20000
       liblinear (array([ 0.99608584,  0.96883584]), 4.099999999951365e-05)
       newton-cg (array([ 0.99608601,  0.96883648]), 3.300000000017178e-05)
           lbfgs (array([ 0.99608665,  0.96883797]), 2.9999999999752447e-05)
             sag (array([ 0.99608603,  0.96883652]), 1.5000000000320313e-05)
```

And also, ... all the versions seem to converge to different coefficients depending on population size. Its almost as if the cost is not normalized by the population size and the effective regularization is C/n. Is that the case?

Comment: To me it looks like everything besides liblinear is converging to the same weights, up to some numerical-precision (first-order vs. second-order methods; surprised to see sag working that good). The liblinear-based approach is probably a bit [hacky](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/779) because of internal design-decisions in regards to regularization (i'm mostly guessing). One more remark: ```max_iter``` effect is drastically different between newton-cg/lbfgs and liblinear/sag i would say (but not sure if it matters for your simple case)

Comment: Yeah -- so what's up with liblinear? Its the default for sk.LogisticRegression.

Also odd: it seems they're optimizing `cost(X,y,w) + (1/C)*reg(w)`, not `cost(X,y,w)/samplesize` + (1/C)*reg(w). This means that as the samplesize increases, the strength of a specific C for regularization decreases. This differs from most descriptions of regularization.

Its not obvious it this is beneficial are harmful, but certainly makes it very hard to make apples-to-apples comparison of sklearn with other libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I turns out different solvers enable different cost and gradient functions.

Here's what I found that different variants optimize:

```
sklearn.LR(solver=liblinear): L + lam*Rb
sklearn.LR(solver=others):    L + lam*R
statsmodels.GLM(bionomial):   L/n + lam*Rb
```

where:

```
lam = 1/C
L = logloss
n = training sample size
R = square of L2 norm of feature weights
Rb =square of L2 norm of feature weights and intercept
```

... its a little odd that sklearn doesn't normalize the loss by the sample size.